# What is the relation between flap setting and aileron droop on the A350?

Tags: aerodynamics, ailerons, airbus-a350, high-lift-device

The A350 has a aileron droop function, which is linked to the flap setting. In contrast to other aircraft with aileron droop, the  A350s ailerons do not droop when the flaps are fully extended.

I would like to know why the ailerons don´t droop when the flaps are fully deployed, and if possible what the scheduling for the aileron droop looks like in relation to the selected flap setting.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the gliders I fly do the same: They do not droop ailerons in full landing configuration but do in intermediate settings. There the reason is aileron effectiveness at high angle of attack and prevention of a tip stall.

If you droop the ailerons it yields more lift but the angle of attack at which the airfoil stalls is decreased, which might give you a more violent stall. And if you suddenly deflect the aileron down further the flow could separate and cause "the wrong wing to go down". To avoid this airliners are often fitted with vortex generators on the outboard section (e.g. Boeing 737) but that was probably a no-go for the clean A350 wings.

Regarding droop vs. flap setting, the FCOM probably has the answer for that. Couldn't find it online yet. A380 does 5 degrees when flaps reach position 1+F or greater, A320 does 5 degrees when flaps reach 1+F or greater so it might be similar with the A350